# Docking Station MAC

Tags: mac, hp, mac-address, dock

Would an HP notebook docking station have its own Ethernet MAC address independent of the internal Ethernet MAC on the laptop itself? I'd test it myself, but the answer decides whether or not we even get one in the first place.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide specific models, it sounds like this is an architectural question.

For cost reasons, most would use a pass-thru. It is also easier to support. However, there are some reasons a designer might want to provide a new ethernet interface, mostly historical. So, the short answer is: you should ask.

Answer (score 0):

My old HP docking station has its own ethernet adapter and that has its own MAC address. If the one you are considering also has its own ethernet adapter, then yes. I don't believe that's just a pass-through port. What model is it?

Answer (score 0):

Most don't come with actual adapters in them anymore...almost all are pass through at this point.

See this link for details on most of HP's offerings in this area: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12075_na/12075_na.HTML and here:  http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13223_div/13223_div.HTML

I think only the NAS 3-in-1 has an actual NIC onboard...the rest pass the signals for audio/video/network/usb through from the laptop.

Comment: In the text of the two links you provided, only the HP 2710p Ultra-Slim uses the phrase "RJ-45 / Ethernet pass thru". The rest use "RJ-45 (network) jack" (or variations) ambiguously. (Except for the NAS model.)

Comment: Not disagreeing with you...it's very ambiguous, just going off of what my PC tech is telling me.

Answer (score 0):

Dell units seem have the same MAC as the docked laptop.